# pyopengl - texture is not rendering as its should

Tags: python, opengl, textures, pyopengl

[image: original]

this is original 2d 256x256 image i am trying to texture on screen. but for some reason it does not rendering without glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) line ever. And when its rendering since pic is 2d i send attrib pointer uv is size of 2 with glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_texture, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
but its turns out this.[image: second]
when i turn it to 3 just for trying sake its like this
[image: third]
what eer i try it did not change any better
what am i doing wrong here? i realy could use another pair of eyes. thank you.
And this is my code:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
# from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram
import numpy as np
from math import radians
from pyrr import matrix44, Vector3
from PIL import Image
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("GLFW not initialized")
window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "personal", None, None)
if not window:
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception("window did not created")
glfw.set_window_pos(window, xpos=200, ypos=50)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
vertices = np.array([-0.7, 0.7, 0.0,
                     -0.7, -0.7, 0.0,
                     0.7, -0.7, 0.0,
                     0.7, 0.7, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)
indices = np.array([0, 1, 3,
                    3, 1, 2], dtype=np.uint32)
# color = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
#                   0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
#                   0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
#                   0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)
texture_coord = np.array([0, 0,
                          0, 1,
                          1, 1,
                          1, 0], dtype=np.uint32)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------- TRANSFORMATION CALCULATION
matrix = matrix44.create_identity(dtype=np.float32)
matrix = np.dot(matrix44.create_from_translation(Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])), matrix)
matrix = np.dot(matrix44.create_from_x_rotation(radians(0)), matrix)
matrix = np.dot(matrix44.create_from_y_rotation(radians(0)), matrix)
matrix = np.dot(matrix44.create_from_z_rotation(radians(0)), matrix)
matrix = np.dot(matrix44.create_from_scale(Vector3([1, 1, 1])), matrix)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
vertex_shader_src = """
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0)in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1)in vec2 texture;
//in vec3 color;//for using color equal it to toFColor
uniform mat4 trans;
out vec3 toFColor;
out vec2 passTexCoord;
void main(){
gl_Position = trans * vec4(position.x,position.y,position.z,1.0f);
//toFColor=color;
passTexCoord=texture;
}
"""
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
fragment_shader_src = """
#version 330 core
//in vec3 toFColor;
in vec2 passTexCoord;
//uniform vec3 triColor;
uniform sampler2D texture_sampler;
out vec4 outColor;
void main(){
//outColor = vec4(toFColor,1.0);
outColor = texture(texture_sampler, passTexCoord);
}
"""
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------PyOpenGL working shader program
# shader_program = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_shader_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
#                         compileShader(fragment_shader_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------tutorial way shader program
vertex_shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
glShaderSource(vertex_shader_id, vertex_shader_src)
glCompileShader(vertex_shader_id)
if glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE:
    print(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader_id))
    print("cant compile shader")
fragment_shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
glShaderSource(fragment_shader_id, fragment_shader_src)
glCompileShader(fragment_shader_id)
if glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE:
    print(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader_id))
    print("cant compile shader")
shader_program = glCreateProgram()
glAttachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader_id)
glAttachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader_id)
glBindAttribLocation(shader_program, 0, "position")
glBindAttribLocation(shader_program, 1, "texture")
glLinkProgram(shader_program)
glValidateProgram(shader_program)
glUseProgram(shader_program)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------- my trying for VAO vertex positions
VAO = glGenVertexArrays(1)  # generate vao
glBindVertexArray(VAO)  # ready VAO to use
VBO1 = glGenBuffers(1)  # generate vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1)  # binding vbo for use
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # setting VBO what to carry
attribute_position = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "position")  # taking attribute name position from shader
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_position)  # ready to use attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                      None)  # telling OpenGL how to read data on given uniform
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- indexing positions
EBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- coloring instead of texture
# i am closing this because i will use texture
# VBO2 = glGenBuffers(1)
# glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2)
# glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color.nbytes, color, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
# attribute_color = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "color")  # taking uniform name color from shader
# glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_color)  # ready to use uniform
# glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_color, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
#                       None)  # telling OpenGL how to read data on given attribute
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Texture pressing
TEX_BO = glGenTextures(1)
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX_BO)
attribute_texture = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "texture")
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_texture)
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_texture, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
texture = Image.open("../res/pic1.png", "r")
texture = texture.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
image_data = texture.convert("RGBA").tobytes()
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture.width, texture.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
# Set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- TRANSFORMATION MATRIX -------------------------
loc_uniform_transformation = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "trans")
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glfw.poll_events()
    glClearColor(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc_uniform_transformation, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix44.create_identity())
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Cleaning
glDeleteTextures(1, int(TEX_BO))
glDetachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader_id)
glDetachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader_id)
glDeleteShader(vertex_shader_id)
glDeleteShader(fragment_shader_id)
glDeleteProgram(shader_program)
glDeleteBuffers(1, int(VBO1))
# glDeleteBuffers(1, int(VBO2)) # if use colors
glDeleteBuffers(1, int(EBO))
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, int(VAO))
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
glfw.destroy_window(window)
glfw.terminate()
```

Comment: Of course you have to set `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)`. The default minifying function is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. Since you do not generate mipmaps, the texture is mipmap incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)` because the default minifying function is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. Since you do not generate mipmaps the texture would be "Mipmap Incomplete" if you do not change the minimize function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

The type of the array of texture coordinates must be `np.float32` rather than `np.uint32`:

```py
texture_coord = np.array([0, 0,
                          0, 1,
                          1, 1,
                          1, 0], dtype=np.float32)
```

You missed to create the buffer object for the texture coordinates:

```py
VBO2 = glGenBuffers(1)  # generate vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2)  # binding vbo for use
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_coord.nbytes, texture_coord, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

attribute_texture = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "texture")
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_texture)
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_texture, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
```

When [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called, the buffer object currently bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the specified vertex attribute.

Comment: thank you it solved the problem. but i wonder why text coord is float32 are they not indices that binding vertices to texture?and  is not glgenTextures a vbo it self

Comment: @AAA `vec2` is a floating point data type. The texture coordinates specify the a relative coordinate on the texture. (0.0, 0.0) is the bottom left. (1.0, 1.0) is the top right. The vertex coordinates and texture coordinates are the attributes. The indices specify the order  of the attributes